# How to add an attribute to a @XmlElementWrapper ArrayList?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm creating the following xml structure with `jaxb`:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "picture")
private List<Picture> pictures;
```

Creates:

```
<pictures>
    <picture/>
    <picture/>
</pictures>
```

What I want:

```
<pictures attribute="test">
    <picture/>
    <picture/>
</pictures>
```

Question: how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

For that you should create one class like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "pictures")
class YourClass{

 @XmlElement(name = "picture")
 private List<Picture> pictures; 

 @XmlAttribute(name="attribute")
 private string attr;
}
```

when you Marshaller this

**pictures** will be your root element, inside that we have one attribute
 **attribute** and other list elements(**picture**) are available inside your root element.

you will get

```
 <pictures attribute="test">
   <picture/>
   <picture/>
 </pictures>
```

Note: you can annotate in getters also.